# Undocumented way to define Identity Server clients in appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I've found an interesting feature while exploring identity server configs. This is how clients should be defined in appsettings.json according to [the official document](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/clients.html):

```
{
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": [
      {
        "ClientId": "TestClient1",
        "RedirectUri": "/redirect",
        "AccessTokenLifetime": 1800
      },
      {
        "ClientId": "TestClient2",
        "RedirectUri": "/redirect",
        "AccessTokenLifetime": 1800
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, one is expected to pass an array of into the "Clients" property of IdentityServer config.

Surprisingly, the following code also works:

```
{
    "IdentityServer": {
        "Clients": {
            "TestClient1": {
                "Profile": "SPA",
                "RedirectUri": "/redirect",
                "AccessTokenLifetime": 1800
            },
            "TestClient2": {
                "Profile": "SPA",
                "RedirectUri": "/redirect",
                "AccessTokenLifetime": 1800
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It passes an object into the "Clients" property. In this case, name of subproperty ("TestClient1", "TestClient2") is mapped to ClientId. RedirectUri also works just fine, but other properties (like AccessTokenLifetime) are skipped.

So, why does it work? Where can I find documents describing this way of IdentityServer configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about this on IdentityServer code really, thats why its not documented. [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/InMemory.cs#L150) is the line of code where it reads the config. As you see it uses [Config.Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Bind_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Object_) extension.